# You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.auth()

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, build.gradle

I'm trying to use firebase Auth in my app and ran into an issue when trying to register a new user.

As far as I can tell RN should autolink so I shouldn't need to manually link any of this yet here I am

I've read so many possible answers on github, firebase documentation and SO that I think I've gotten my self even more turned around and confused about whats going on.

Below is the code my google searches have told me are important to this problem

Any help is much appreciated.

---

Register.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Image,
    Text,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Alert,
    TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default function Register({ navigation }) {

    const popAction = () => {
        navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(1));
    }

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [c_password, setC_Password] = useState('');
    //const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    //const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [showLoading, setShowLoading] = useState(false);

    const register = async() => {
        setShowLoading(true);
        try {
            const doRegister = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
            setShowLoading(false);
            if(doRegister.user) {
                navigation.navigate('Home');
                console.log('User registered successfully!')
            }
        } catch (e) {
            setShowLoading(false);
            Alert.alert(
                e.message
            );
        }
    }

    passCheck = () => {
        if (password != c_password) {
            Alert.alert(
                e.message
            );
        } else {
            register()

        }
    }

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.topMenu}>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.back}
                    activeOpacity={0.6}
                    underlayColor="#1ABC9C"
                    onPress={popAction}
                >
                    <Image style={styles.back}
                        source={require('../../images/icons/back.png')}
                    />
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.logo}>
                <Text style={styles.logoText}>
                    Register
                </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.registerContainer}>
                {/*
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='First Name'
                    value={firstName}
                    onChangeText={setFirstName}
                />
                */}
                {/*
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Last Name'
                    value={lastName}
                    onChangeText={setLastName}
                />
                */}
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Your Email'
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                />
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Your Password'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                />
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Confirm Password'
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    value={c_password}
                    onChangeText={setC_Password}
                />
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    activeOpacity={0.6}
                    underlayColor="#1ABC9C"
                    title="Login"
                    onPress={this.passCheck}
                >
                    <Text>
                        Register
                    </Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        </View>
    )  
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#1ABC9C'
    },
    topMenu: {
        height: deviceHeight/10,
        marginLeft: deviceWidth/30,
        marginRight: deviceWidth/30,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    back: {
        height: deviceHeight/15,
        width: deviceHeight/15,
    },
    logo: {
        height: 2*(deviceHeight/10),
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    logoText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 60
    },
    registerContainer: {
        height: 7*(deviceHeight/10),
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    input: {
        height: deviceHeight/15,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    button:{
        height: deviceHeight/15,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 50,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonText:{
        color: '#1ABC9C',
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 30
    }
});
```

android/build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: 'base'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.andrewbrook.nghbrly"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }



    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'nghbrly'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, './../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
```

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.nghbrly;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;
import io.invertase.firebase.app.RNFirebaseAppPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.auth.RNFirebaseAuthPackage;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new RNFirebaseAppPackage());
          packages.add(new RNFirebaseAuthPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
   * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
   *
   * @param context
   * @param reactInstanceManager
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(
      Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.nghbrly.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass
            .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
            .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```